# Does protocol array elements passed by value or reference?

Tags: swift, oop, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

I know Structs are passed by value and classes are passed by reference in Swift.

I wonder if I create an array store elements which providing a protocol. These elements passed by value or reference?

Is it based on the definition of model a class or struct?

```
class ClassA: ProtocolA {
// something
}

struct StructA: ProtocolA {
// something
}

var arr: [ProtocolA] = [ClassA(), StructA()]

exampleFunction(arr[0]) // is it passed by reference
exampleFunction(arr[1]) // is it passed by value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols should be seen as value types because you need to explicitly tell the compiler that it is a reference type by defining it as conforming to AnyObject (which all classes conform to)

So if you have

```
protocol ProtocolB: AnyObject
```

then any type conforming to ProtocolB will be sent by reference and otherwise not.

Here is a simplified example

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    var x: Int { get set }
}

protocol ProtocolB: AnyObject {
    var y: Int { get set }
}

class ClassA: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}

func exampleFunction(_ object: ProtocolA) {
    object.x += 2 // <-- This will generate a compilation error
}

func exampleFunction(_ object: ProtocolB) {
    object.y += 2 // This is fine
}
```

Comment: Why first exampleFunction generate error?

Comment: Because `object` is let declared (constant)

Comment: If I put it down as a `func exampleFunction(_ object: inout ProtocolA)` is it still a constant?

Comment: @excE Why not try yourself?

Comment: Thanks for all answers. It is crystal clear now. I tried it and it worked for both struct and class with `&` and `inout`

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how the array is declared, the class is passed by reference, and the structure is passed by value. This can be demonstrated with the following example:

```swift
protocol ProtocolA {
    var title: String { get set}
}

class ClassA: ProtocolA {
    var title = "ClassA"
}

struct StructA: ProtocolA {
    var title = "StructA"
}

var arr: [ProtocolA] = [ClassA(), StructA()]

print(arr[0].title) // ClassA
print(arr[1].title) // StructA

func exampleFunction(_ obj: ProtocolA) {
    var obj = obj // Create local mutable variable
    obj.title = obj.title + "!!!"
}

exampleFunction(arr[0])
exampleFunction(arr[1])

print(arr[0].title) // ClassA!!!
print(arr[1].title) // StructA
```

Comment: You are not updating the object passed in to the function for the struct so I am not sure what this example proves?

Comment: The question was whether the object is passed by reference or by value, and not how to change the passed object inside the function. The example shows that the class is passed by reference, since changes to `title` take place after the function is completed.

Comment: OK, I got a little confused by your wording then but note that question is really about protocols and not objects.

Answer (score 1):

When you store a variable as a protocol type, the compiler handles it as if it was a value type. So if `exampleFunction` takes an input argument of type `ProtocolA`, in order for you to be able to mutate a property of the input argument, you need to declare it as `inout`.

This doesn't mean that the values are necessarily passed by value, it just means the compiler has no idea whether the input argument is a value or a reference type, so at compile-time it handles it as a value type.

If you want to be able to handle a protocol variable as a reference type, you need to make the protocol class bound. `protocol ProtocolA: class {}`